# Why does SpaCy change the entire dependency tree because of a capital letter?

Tags: spacy

## The problem:

spaCy will produce a different parse tree if a single word is capitalized.

### Examples:

- Ketone is negative, **protein** is negative, Leucocytes is negative
- Ketone is negative, **Protein** is negative, Leucocytes is negative

When **Protein** is capitalized, spacy produces 2 dependency trees and when **protein** only one tree, see the attached photo.

[image]

## Environment:

windows server 2019,spaCy:2.1.4,spaCy-model: en_core_web_md

## Questions:

- Why does SpaCy change the entire dependency tree because of a capital letter?
- Is there any way to make this more consistent?